# Displaying the Incorrect Cost

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement

My goal is to display the cost for a **One-Day Conference** on a web page, which is $50.00.  However, I keep getting $0.00 in return.  I tested my SELECT statement in SQL and it is retrieving the correct data.  Now I have narrowed down the problem to be in my `if...else if` statements in the **PayBackCC** method but I am not certain.  It should get the cost from variable `cOneDCost`.  Any help is appreciated.

Code behind

```
protected void PayBackInfo()
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand PBCredit = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM PaymentInfo, ConferenceReg WHERE PaymentInfoID=PaymentInfoIDNum AND PaymentInfoID=@payID AND ConferenceReg.Deleted='N' AND ConferenceIDNum=@confID", con);
        PBCredit.Parameters.AddWithValue("@confID", confID);
        PBCredit.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payID", Request.QueryString["payID"]);

        SqlDataReader readerPB = PBCredit.ExecuteReader();
        while (readerPB.Read())
        {
            piID = readerPB["PaymentInfoID"].ToString();
            cID = readerPB["ConferenceIDNum"].ToString();
            poID = readerPB["PurchaseOrder"].ToString();
            partnersNum = readerPB["PartnersIDNum"].ToString();
            cFullCost = Convert.ToDecimal(readerPB["ConferenceFullFee"]).ToString("#,##0.00");
            cOneDCost = Convert.ToDecimal(readerPB["ConferenceOneDayFee"]).ToString("#,##0.00");
            partnersCost = Convert.ToDecimal(readerPB["PartnersFee"]).ToString("#,##0.00");

            PayBackCC();
        }
        readerPB.Close();
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}


private void PayBackCC()
{
    if (!partnersNum.Equals("null") || !partnersNum.Equals("0"))
    {
        msgLbl.Text = "$" + partnersCost;
    }
    else if (!cFullCost.Equals("0"))
    {
        msgLbl.Text = "$" + cFullCost;
    }
    else if (!cOneDCost.Equals("0"))
    {
        msgLbl.Text = "$" + cOneDCost;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you take the time to start your debugger and follow your code path I think you will discover very quickly where the problem is

Comment: Think about this statement: `!X || !Y`. When would this be true and when would this be false? The answer should clue you in on what is wrong.

Comment: How many records your query returns? If thereis only one row in return do not use while, just call Read() method

Comment: @Steve: Thank you.  I will try the debugger.

Comment: @Yuri: Just one row was returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change

```
 if (!partnersNum.Equals("null") || !partnersNum.Equals("0"))
```

to

```
 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(partnersNum) || !partnersNum.Equals("0"))
```

unless you are expecting "null" string from your query

Comment: For some reason, my DB manager had set the column for PartnersIDNum to be null, unless specified otherwise.

Comment: yes, but "null" as a string you were testing and DBNull (NULL) are not the same.

Comment: @EstherB suppose for a moment that your `partnersNum` is NULL, Your if will be taken because `partnersNum` is not 0. Now, if your `partnersNum` is '0' your same if will be taken because `partnersNum` is not null. With this code there is no chance that you get the else if blocks executed,

Comment: @Steve I appreciate your explanation.  I understand my problem now.